# Forward Loop or Reverse Loop depending what random number is generated?

Tags: java

I am trying to work this logic out but cannot seem to get it going. I would appreciate any direction on this please. I would like a method to generate a 
random number between 1 and 10 and then return an array of four elements of a local String[] array "numArr" which is a local member of the method. so lets say, if
the generated random number is "8", I would then have a reverse for loop starting on "8" and return:

"eight"
"seven"
"six"
"five"

I have a local variable "len" which is set to 4, "len" variable determines how many elements of "numArr" needs to be return. I am making sure that the generated random
number is less than (numArr.length - len) so if the generate random number is 8, my logic will determine and employ the reverse loop starting on 8. Because if a 
forward loop is invoked, it will only be executed twice because "numArr" only has 10 elements.

I am running the reverse for loop:

if current random number > (numArr.length - len). so if the random number is 7,8,9,or 10, logic will run reverse for loop.

I am currently not returning anything, I just want to make sure the logic is fully functional before I return anything.

```
public static void geNums(){

    //LENGTH IS SET TO 4
    int len = 4;

    //COUNTER
    int counter = 0;

    //LOCAL ARRAY WITH JUS 10 ELEMENTS
    String[] numArr = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};       

    //RANDOM NUMBER IS GENERATED BETWEEN 1 AND 10
    Random randNum = new Random();      
    int curRandom = randNum.nextInt(9) + 0; //0 TO 9 || 1 TO 10

    //CHOICE ARRAY
    String[] choices = new String[ len ];   //LENGTH IS SET TO 4

    //DISPLAY CURRENTLY GENERATED RANDOM NUMBER
    System.out.println("Current Random Number: " + curRandom);
    System.out.println("-------------------------");

    if(curRandom > (numArr.length - len)){

        //REVERSE LOOP
        for(int i = curRandom; i >= len; i--){

        //BREAK IF COUNTER IS MORE THAN LEN
        if(counter > len){
            --counter;
            break;
        }
        choices[i] = numArr[i];     //POPULATE CHOICE ARRAY
        ++counter;
    }
    else{
        //FORWARD LOOP
        for(int i = curRandom; i < len; i++){
            choices[i] = numArr[i]; //POPULATE CHOICE ARRAY
        }       
    }

    //DISPLAY CHOICE ARRAY ELEMENTS FOR DUBUGGING
    for(int j = 0; j < choices.length; j++){
        System.out.println(choices[j]);
    }

}//METHOD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you generate a number between 1..10. If it is greater thar five you save its string name into an array. I have moddified your code a little I hope you understand.
One first problem that I found is here for(int `i = curRandom`; i >= len; i--) ....`choices[i]` = numArr[i]. Remeber that your array (choices) is declaread of length 4 :`String[] choices = new String[ len ];   //LENGTH IS SET TO 4` So what if you generate number 8? You start whith `i` from 8 and when you call `choices[i]` which is equal whith `choices[8]`
it would give an `IndexOutOfBoundException` because your array is only 4. So here is a solution:

```
//LENGTH IS SET TO 4
            int len = 4;

            //COUNTER
            int counter = 0;

            //LOCAL ARRAY WITH JUS 10 ELEMENTS
            String[] numArr = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};       

            //RANDOM NUMBER IS GENERATED BETWEEN 1 AND 10
            Random randNum = new Random();      
            int curRandom = randNum.nextInt(9) + 0; //0 TO 9 || 1 TO 10

            //CHOICE ARRAY
            String[] choices = new String[ len ];   //LENGTH IS SET TO 4

            //DISPLAY CURRENTLY GENERATED RANDOM NUMBER
            System.out.println("Current Random Number: " + curRandom);
            System.out.println("-------------------------");

            if(curRandom > 5){
                int aux = curRandom;
                for(int i = 0;i<len;i++) {
                    choices[i] = numArr[aux];
                    aux--;
                }
            }
            else {
                int aux = curRandom;
                for(int i = 0;i<len;i++) {
                    choices[i] = numArr[aux];
                    aux++;
                }
            }


            //DISPLAY CHOICE ARRAY ELEMENTS FOR DUBUGGING
            for(int j = 0; j < choices.length; j++)
                System.out.println(choices[j]);
```

Output:

```
Current Random Number: 2
-------------------------
three
four
five
six
```